# PostgreSQL: Why does this simple query not use the index?

Tags: database, postgresql, relational-database, database-performance

I have a table t with a column c, which is an int and has a btree index on it.

Why does the following query not utilize this index?

```
explain select c from t group by c;
```

The result I get is:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=1005817.55..1005817.71 rows=16 width=4)
  ->  Seq Scan on t  (cost=0.00..946059.84 rows=23903084 width=4)
```

My understanding of indexes is limited, but I thought such queries were the purpose of indexes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The query certainly can use an index.  The reason that it doesn't in your particular case depends on the particular size and distribution of the data.  You can use `SET enable_seqscan TO off` to investigate.

Comment: Under what kinds of circumstances would it not pay off to not use an index? I cannot imagine any distribution at least when we are talking about the size in this example.

Comment: @David: A whole-index scan is much more expensive than a sequential scan of the table.  An index would generally only be useful if you select a small subset of the table.

Comment: This is just wrong. A query like `SELECT DISTINCT x FROM t;` should be able to use an index on `(x)`. Reading the whole index should be less expensive than reading the whole table. But Postgres has not implemented as far as I know [Loose Index scans](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan)

Answer (score 6):

This query can be performed using an optimization called a *loose index scan*. However PostgreSQL doesn't yet implement this optimization, so it uses a table scan instead.

Of the major databases, as far as I know only [MySQL has implemented loose index scan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/loose-index-scan.html) (perhaps Oracle too?). PostgreSQL [hasn't](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan) implemented this feature.

Comment: Postgresql's architecture means that currently it HAS to visit the table even if it uses the index.  That is much more expensive when you've got to hit every row anyway.  I assume in mysql the engine would have to include covering indexes to work properly, but I don't know mysql all that well.

Comment: @Scott Marlowe: But the main point is that if a loose index scan can be used you *don't* have to hit every row. This is why MySQL can be hundreds or thousands of times faster than PostgreSQL for this sort of query (on very large tables where there are very few distinct values of `c`). It's a low priority feature request because a simple change in the schema design (introducing a new table) solves the problem.

Comment: It's also called an *index only scan* and  Oracle, SQL Server, and DB2 implement this as well. But I doubt that it makes a query *thousands of times faster*. Faster, yes. But not in that order of magnitude (but I agree it's really a shame that Postgres does not have that)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: No, an index only scan is something entirely different and gives only a very small speed up. A loose index scan can give several orders of magnitude improvement. For one million rows and 100 distinct values  the query in SQL Server can take about 1 second, and in MySQL it takes just a few milliseconds. Oracle has an index skip scan which is almost the same thing, but I'm not sure that an index skip scan query plan can be used here - I think it requires at least two columns to be referenced in the query. The underlying algorithm however is roughly the same.

Answer (score 3):

Because it requires scanning the entire table, so doing that via the index is of no benefit. ("Covering indices" aren't useful as a performance technique in PostgreSQL due to its MVCC implementation).

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.2 will come with index-only scans: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.2#Index-only_scans